# ractive event propagates even when handler returns false

Tags: ractivejs

ref: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9g3pB/36) (modified version of the tooltip example in the [docs](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/writing-decorator-plugins/%22docs%22))

html:

```
<div id='container'></div>
<script id='tpl' type='text/ractive'>
  < h1 > Tooltip decorator < /h1>
  <div onclick="say_hi()">
    This text contains 
    <span id="decorated" decorator='tooltip:A tooltip is a blah blah...'>tooltips</span > < /div>
</script>
```

javascript:

```
    say_hi = function () {
    alert(this.event.target.id)
}

var tooltipDecorator = function (node, content) {
    var tooltip, click;

    click = function () {
        tooltip = document.createElement('p');
        tooltip.className = 'ractive-tooltip';
        tooltip.textContent = content;

        node.parentNode.insertBefore(tooltip, node);
    };

    node.addEventListener('click', click, false);

    return {
        teardown: function () {}
    }
};


Ractive.decorators.tooltip = tooltipDecorator;

ractive = new Ractive({
    el: 'container',
    template: '#tpl'
});
```

The docs suggest that event bubbling is prevented by returning 'false' from the handler, as the tooltip example in the documentation does. However by capturing events on a parent element, it can be seen that events are in fact propagating (click on the word "tooltips" and the alert from the parent div indicates that it's catching the click)

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I don't see any Ractive events in the code example. I also don't see where you're returning false.

Comment: you're right, @martypdx, the event controlling the tooltip is not a ractive event but just a plain-old-js-event. And false is not being returned. Thanks for taking the time to look at it.